# File download required before validation (mobile)

Tags: forms, validation, download, gdpr

In mobile app I working on, I need force the user to download a file (GDPR) before validating a form. I dont have idea how to make it user-friendly. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use-case? Describe, what is the form, what is the file, why does the user have to download it, what do they have to do after downloading it and what's the validation process.

Comment: @exp It's the penultimate mockup before payment (product purchase process). Our management need the user will download a pdf file (GDPR info), otherwise he will not able to proceed to the last step. I think forcing user to download file is not good idea, but I need to look for a useful solution.

Comment: Please provide more details. Can you add images that show the problem? Why is it not user friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all - assuming that the purpose of them downloading the file is to agree to the terms of use, privacy policy or data processing rules - I should note that downloading a file is not an assurance that a person has read the Privacy Policy and - even less so - that they've agreed to it.

Second of all, making somebody download a file in a mobile app setting is definitely not a common or understandable use case, especially on iOS. That's not ok even on desktops. It is both very bad UX and terrible for user security and would undoubtfully introduce a lot of problems.

That said, consider these solutions:

1. The most natural solution would a checkbox "agree to data processing rules" with a link that would download a file. And the payment button would be disabled before the checkbox is checked. Checkbox is a somewhat good way to get consent from the user - that way have to click to agree. Lawyers are usually happy about that.
2. You could also show a separate page with all the info the user needs, including all the download buttons and a CTA button to confirm. In essence, the user fill out the form, presses a button to submit, you display them a confirmation page which you could use as a place to display the download buttons and all the confirmation info you need. The user reads it and presses the button to confirm the submition and it's done.

**Please consider showing the contents of the infamous file in natural way inside your app, don't make the user download anything on their device.**